# How to display only those values that are not part of another array

Tags: jquery

Sorry if this is a dumb question . but i was not successful in implementing this .

I am trying to showing all the codes that are present under `allcodes`  array, **except** that were present under `dontshowthesecodes` array .

I was trying this way

could you please let me know how to do this

```
var dontshowthesecodes = ["C", "D"];

var allcodes  = ["A", "B" , "C" , "D" , "E" , "F"];

for(var i=0;i<allcodes.length;i++)
{
if($.inArray(allcodes[i], dontshowthesecodes) > -1)
{
      console.log(allcodes[i])
} 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ku720du/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a jQuery object containing the original array, then use `not()` to return the difference between the two:

`$( allcodes ).not( dontshowthesecodes ).get();`

Given your example this would give you the following array:

```
['A', 'B', 'E', 'F'];
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8988rf6t/1/)

Comment: Thank you but i need this in the for loop as i need to implement some logic

Comment: You could either use the answer above and loop over its result, or use the code you have already, it's fine except for the `> -1`, it should be `== -1`